# Passing char* to singly listed list changes all its elements

Tags: c, pointers, char, singly-linked-list

I've narrowed down the problem to this very specific detail, but I still can't see to find a solution. I kinda feel why this happens, but being new to pointers, I dont know how to fix it.

So I have a singly linked list with a function to add elements to the beginning of it and another to list its elements. Both work fine.

I wanna go through a loop, passing different values to a `char *variable` before adding it to the singly linked list with the `insert(variable)` function.

Here is the behavior I get:

```
    variable = "aa";
    insert(variable);
    list();
```

`List: aa`

```
    variable = "aa";
    insert(variable);
    variable = "bb";
    insert(variable);
    list();
```

`List: bb bb`

```
    variable = "aa";
    insert(variable);
    variable = "bb";
    insert(variable);
    variable = "cc";
    insert(variable);
    list();
```

`List: cc cc cc`

Obviously the wanted result would be: `List: cc bb aa`. why is this happening?

CODE:

```
    while (fgets(word_in_file, LENGTH, file) != NULL) {
        word_to_add = malloc((LENGTH) * sizeof(char));
        strcpy(word_to_add, word_in_file);
        insert(word_to_add);
    }
```

Thanks!

Comment: Obviously your code is somehow broken. We can't say more without seeing the code.

Comment: You should add how you implement `insert()` and `list()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You problem is you are using the same char pointer who is pointing to same memory location. So last value you entered will reflect in all place. Better allocate memory dynamically every time just before you enter a value in it.

Just add the below line of code:-

```
variable = malloc(3);
strcpy(variable, "aa");
insert(variable);
variable = malloc(3);
strcpy(variable, "bb");
insert(variable);
variable = malloc(3);
strcpy(variable, "cc");
insert(variable);
```

Now you will get aa, bb, cc

Also do not forget to release dynamically allocate memory.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks a lot. I kinda knew that this was the problem, but I still couldn't figure out what to do.

Comment: In this case, how could I go about freeing the memory? `free(variable)` would only free the memory used for the last malloc.

Comment: @Victor, you have to use `free` to the variable where you have assign the pointer with `insert(variable);` at the end of the program. Probably you have to use a function through which you need to release the memory at the end of the program.

Comment: What I am saying is that `variable = malloc(); insert(variable)` is gonna get called thousands of time inside my loop. And as I understand, I cannot free the memory after each call (or the behavior described at OP will occur). So I'd have to free the memory outside the loop. Is there a way to free all those calls?

Comment: I added the code on the OP.